# Xamarin The application could not be started

Tags: xamarin

Hi everyones i got a anoying problem:

```
The application could not be started. Ensure that the application has been installed to the target device and has a launchable activity (MainLauncher = true).
```

Things i do:

- adb uninstall ; nothing happens
- try to uninstal app from device: the app dont apeard, even like a fake app whith 0kb
- Uninstall Mono Shared Runtine and Api from app
- Factory reset
- Check in another device

Nothing solve my problem and i dont know who i must do.

Add:

My MainActivity;

```
 [Activity(Label = "AppTecnicos", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error (Finally): my app package name started with uppercase.

```
AppTecnicos.Droid
```

I changed it to:

```
appTecnicos.Droid
```

Answer (score 1):

> The application could not be started. Ensure...has a **launchable activity** (MainLauncher = true).

One `Activity` in your application needs to be assigned as the `MainLauncher` otherwise the Android OS does not know the main entry point to app and what to display.

In `Xamarin.Android` typically this is done via the `ActivityAttribute` by assigning `MainLauncher = true`.

Example:

```
[Activity(Label = "StackOverflow", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
  ~~~
}
```

Ref: [ActivityAttribute Class](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.App.ActivityAttribute/)

Comment: They got MainLaucher = true

Answer (score 0):

If you are using visual studio and your aplication is a Xamarin.Forms aplication, this could be happening due to a solution configuration problem.

In that case, try to open the solution properties and within the configuration properties section check that your proyect its checked for deploy.