# No Launch-able Activity even though it's set for Xamarin Forms v4.2.0.848062

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.3.2, on windows 10, and having a fairly complicated issue.

Even though MainLauncher is set as follows:

```
[Activity(Label = "AppName", Icon = "@drawable/Icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity {...}
```

I get this error when starting a debugging session:

> No Launchable Activity: This project does not contain any activities
>   marked MainLauncher. It has been deployed to the device, but no
>   activity will be launched. To mark an activity as launchable, add the
>   [Activity] attribute to it with MainLauncher = true: [Activity
>   (MainLauncher = true)] public class MyActivity : Activity

Based on previous fixes ([naming issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225183/xamarin-the-application-could-not-be-started), [deleting files](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/68620/no-launchable-activity-found-dialog-when-deploying-app)), I deleted bin and obj folders in Visual studio, checked naming issues, clean/rebuild, restart visual studio, and then start debugging, but the error still occurs. Also, the app is not installed on the target device/simulator in either debug or release after the "Deploy Succeeded".

See [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/741982/systemtypeinitializationexception-the-type-initial-2.html) for more details regarding before the updates were installed and this no launch-able activity issue occurs. (note that on this configuration, the app IS installed on the target device, however it crashes. The only thing that has changed since the release to production, is the Visual Studio Updates have been installed.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to roll back to the previous version,see if it works

Comment: I had to create a new project and copy over the code. I still have no idea why this happened.

Comment: I had the same issue. Turns out that the Activity: Label had the wrong name. Changing it my xamarin forms project name fixed it for me. To debug your issue, try creating a a fresh xamarin project, and compare the android manifest file, and your MainActivity.cs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved by Steema.

It was an issue with the libraries installed. Xamarin.Forms made changes that bricked the library; after they updated it, it worked fine.